# unix - print distinct list of control characters in a file

Tags: linux, perl, bash, shell, unix

For example given an input file like below:

```
sid|storeNo|latitude|longitude
2|1|-28.03õ720000
9|2
10
jgn
352|1|-28.03¿720000
9|2|fd¿kjhn422-405
000¥0543210|gf¿djk39
gfd|f¥d||fd
```

Output (the characters below can appear in any order):

```
¿õ¥
```

Does anyone have a function (awk, bash, perl.etc) that could scan each line and then output (in octal, hex or ascii - either is fine) a distinct list of the control characters (for simplicity, control characters being those above ascii char 126) found?

Using perl v5.8.8.

Comment: Why not just decode with the appropriate charset in the first place?

Comment: @Ignacio - ideally, yes. but receive data from external sources, so would be useful to be able to run this check.

Comment: Nit: There is only one "ascii char above 126", as ASCII only has 128 characters (numbered 0-127). You mean "byte" when you say "ascii char".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print the bytes in octal:

```
perl -ne'printf "%03o\n", ord for /[^\x09\x0A\x20-\x7E]/g' file  | sort -u
```

To print the bytes in hex:

```
perl -ne'printf "%02X\n", ord for /[^\x09\x0A\x20-\x7E]/g' file  | sort -u
```

To print the original bytes:

```
perl -nE'say for /[^\x09\x0A\x20-\x7E]/g' file  | sort -u
```

Comment: what does "%02X\n", ord   mean?

Comment: @toop, `"%02X\n"` is a format pattern for [`printf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html). [`ord`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ord.html) returns the character number of the first character of the string passed as its argument, which defaults to value of `$_`.

Comment: Thanks, what would be the change to make it print the original input character? ie. ¿

Answer (score 2):

This should catch everything over ordinal value 126 without having to explicitly weed out outliers

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -n1 c; do 
  if (( $(printf "%d" "'$c") > 126)); then
    echo "$c"
  fi
done < ./infile | sort -u
```

#### Output

```
¥
¿
õ
```

Comment: what does "IFS= read -n1 c;" do and what is the single quote in "'$c" for?

Answer (score 2):

To delete everything except the control characters:

```
tr -d '\0-\176' < input > output
```

To test:

```
printf 'foobar\n\377' | tr -d '\0-\176' | od -t c
```

See [tr(1) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) for details.

Comment: +1, I like this. `tr -d '\0-\177' < ./infile| sed 's/./&\n/g' | sort -u` to get what the OP was looking for, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's/[A-Za-z0-9,|]//g' -e 's/-//g' -e 's/./&^M/g' | sort -u
```

Delete everything you don't want, put everything else on its own line, then sort -u the whole kit.

The "&^M" is "&" followed by Ctrl-V followed by Ctrl-M in Bash.

Unix wins.

Comment: That outputs "." if in the input.